# How do I resolve foreign key constraint error while creating schema

Tags: mysql, sql, key, constraints

I am trying to create a schema with few tables. 
I've tried running this script, but I've received an error `cannot add foreign key constraint`. I could not find the problem,

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE Review
(
    reviewId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    prankId INT,
    rating INT,
    comment VARCHAR(1056) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(reviewId),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES User(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (prankId) REFERENCES Prank(prankId)
);

CREATE TABLE Prank
(
    prankId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    prankName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(1056) NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(prankId)
);
```

Comment: if you guys require the whole schema, do let me know

Comment: You have to create the `Prank` table before `Review`. You can't have a foreign key reference a table that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CREATE TABLE for `Prank`, before creating `Review`. So `Review` can refer to `Prank` after its being created and can know which table and which field of that table you are asking a field to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE Prank
(
prankId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
prankName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(1056) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(18,4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(prankId)
);

CREATE TABLE Review
(
reviewId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
prankId INT,
rating INT,
comment VARCHAR(1056) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(reviewId),
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES User(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (prankId) REFERENCES Prank(prankId));
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/952f7)

Basically this line

```
FOREIGN KEY (prankId) REFERENCES Prank(prankId)
```

is creating the issue ie, you need to first create the `Prank` table as you are refering  the columns of it in your `Review` table.